# Hadoop on Virtual Machines

Tags: mysql, virtual-machines, vmware-esxi, hadoop

We would like to migrate from MySQL to Hadoop for scalability.
Will hadoop clusters running on virtual machines improve our website's performance?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of implementing hadoop cluster on virtual machines(ESXi).

Answer (score 5):

Hadoop is a scalable data processing platform.
MySQL is a relational database for realtime usage.

HBase (running on HDFS --> Hadoop Distributed File System) is a BigTable implementation: Big tables but not relational!

Can you map your application into these constraints?
Only if you can do this mapping then the question of "will it perform" is a useful question.

Answer (score 1):

Jonar 
No, you cannot use Hadoop. Hadoop and tools built on hadoop like Pig and Hive are good choices for backend processes where throughput matters more than response time. Since you want to power a website, I am asuuming that you need subsecond response times, nothing beats RDBMS for that. Hadoop will be slow for you even if you use dedicated machines. Virtual machines will not add any value for you

As Niels has mentioned, you can use Hbase but chances are very high that you will not be easily able to adapt your MySql processes to Hbase so I will encourage you to understand Hbase and know its limitations.